# is Ultralite supported for Android?

Tags: android, sybase

if yes, is there a tutorial available for creating an android app using the same?

if no, what db can i use apart from from SQLite, i need to keep the DB seperate from other apps.

Comment: I couldn't find what Ultralite refers to. Is it a DB? Anyway, SQLite is the most appropriate DB choice on Android; it's built-in to each and every device and the Android SDK includes plenty of support using for SQLite in various ways.

Comment: yeah its a DB, from Sybase, i'll migrate the Ultralite DB to SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ultralite, but I see it is available as .jar files and Java files, so it is very likely to work if included as a library.

Android only supports a subset of java.* and javax.*, but I've looked at the import statements in the .java files and there doesn't seem anything too exotic, I think you'll be OK.

I'm a bit puzzled by this

> what db can i use apart from from SQLite, i need to keep the DB seperate from other apps.

There is no reason why using SQLite will inhibit your need to keep the DB separate from other apps. In fact the design of Android makes it very difficult to do anything else than keep apps' data separate. In fact, one of my apps has three different SQLite databases internally. So you are not limited to a single SQLite database, even within an app.

Comment: thanks Jim, 

about the "keeping the db" seperate part, i wasn't aware about the Android architecture that well. i'm porting a winMo app (part of a suite) to android and hadn't read up that well on Android. Think i'll move the Ultralite DBs to SQLite too....

cheers mate